# How to switch on MFA for a specific group of usres in cloud Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In our Azure B2C user list we have normal users and users with administrator privilege in the target application. We have the requirement to switch on MFA for these administrators, but I can not find how to do that in Azure B2C.

**How to switch on multi-factor authentication for a specific user group, not for all?**

Comment: Hi, Is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the process below:

`Users` >> `All users` >> `Multi-Factor Authentication` >> `Select the user you want to add MFA`>> `Enabled`

[image]
[image]
[image]

As far as I understand, only users who are licensed to use Microsoft Online Services are eligible for multi-factor authentication.Before starting, please follow this link for multi-factor authentication deployment[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted).

Comment: This looks really promising.. I followed these steps, but when I activate MFA for a user and start the user flow "sign in" (run userflow), the user can enter the password, but just remains on the login screen. So nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? (user flow has mfa off, user has mfa on)

Comment: @Arthur Did you choose version 1.1.0 in Page Layout Version?

Comment: No, I am using version 1.2.0, but if I change to 1.1.0 it does not work either. I've activated javascript for the userflow > no change. When I activate mfa for a user and logon, the screen now comes back with a 'code' before the domain name (e.g. aef1bee2-7f23-48e0-8b68-03366daxxxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com)

Comment: Not sure if that give more useful info, but when I use the link provided by Azure when activating mfa (https://aka.ms/MFASetup), I can not do anything. Message: account/ password invalid.